# Importing Excel file using Roo, error: Supplying `packed` or `file_warning` as separate arguments to `Roo::Excel.new` is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

Import Code:

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    region = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    region.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
    region.save!
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

Error:

```
Supplying `packed` or `file_warning` as separate arguments to `Roo::Excel.new` is deprecated. Use an options hash instead.
```

I know I need to pass an `options = {}` somewhere, but I'm not sure where. I've googled this and saw some example codes but they are for completely different uses.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing:

```
when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
```

to

```
when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, packed: nil, file_warning: :ignore)
when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, packed: nil, file_warning: :ignore)
when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, packed: nil, file_warning: :ignore)
```

Looks like what you have currently is an older version of the Roo:: method calls.

The [initialize method for the current version of roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/707ed1524dd4506e553c6528a674add910598395/lib/roo/excelx.rb#L251) expects a filename & an options parameter.  Setting `file.path, packed: nil, file_warning: :ignore` as the params will make it use the first param as the filename, and the remaining params as a hash of options.

Comment: Thank you! that was the correct fix for using the old method call without the error.